# Programming an Attitude Control/Avionics System in Assembly

Tags: assembly, astronomy

I am currently working with a team of amateur rocketrists (well, "amateur" is a stretch, all of us have completed, are enrolled in or have applied for relevant university degree programmes) on a project to send a satellite into orbit. Having done mainly high-level programming so far (*VB.NET*, *Python*, *PHP*), with a little dabble in *FIG-FORTH*, I was wondering about what language to learn and use in order to program the attitude control/avionics system for the carrier spacecraft.

Of course, since efficiency both in terms of speed and storage are a big issue here, one thing that came to mind was Assembly. My question: Is it feasible to do this, i.e. to program an automated attitude control system in Assembly?

It seems like something awfully complex to do in such an extremely low-level programming language, so I wanted to know whether people with more experience in the field could weigh in with whether Assembly would be a good option, or whether something still low-level but slightly easier to handle like *FORTH*, *FORTRAN* or *C* would result in significant time savings compared to the penalty they incur in terms of program size and speed.

Comment: “Is it feasible to do this, i.e. to program an automated attitude control system in Assembly?” You have to realize that mostly all members of this site only know about “automated attitude control system” what you have told them in your question. This is not enough information for anyone to give an informed opinion (and for this reason, your question is not really a good fit for this site and may be put “on hold”, although I am personally taking a wait-and-see attitude with this one).

Comment: Know assembly, perhaps a few lines here and there but as with any embedded (bare metal) project it is not a bad idea to write the thing mostly in C.  In any case you should learn C even if you dont use that for your project and assembly as well but dont start bother with x86 (having the hardware is a horrible excuse), learn msp430, or arm or some other better instruction set first.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Well, explaining an automated attitude control system is something that automatically controls the orientation of a spacecraft so that it goes into the direction you want it to, keeping it stable. I assumed that was common knowledge. A quick Google search'll tell you the same thing anyway. Such software needs to analyse sensory input and make determinations for the movement of steering components like rudders, based on mathematical models of the physics involved.

Comment: @dwelch Thank you very much. In what respects is msp430 better than x86, though? I do have spare Celerons lying around, so using x86 would be cheaper, is it really bad?

Comment: If it is your first assembly language then yes it is very bad.  Second learn assembly on an instruction set simulator first not on hardware.  Your chance of success, frustration level, overall learning experience will benefit.  Once you have learned 4 or 5 good instruction sets then maybe look at the 8086/8088 then work up to the current x86 processors if you really feel the need.  If you are doing an embedded project you wont be, shouldnt be, using x86 anyway.  Certainly not something rad hard for space.

Comment: @FredericBayer I have several automation projects in assembly language and IMO, it is good for such things. Assembly programs tend to be light, fast and as a result of the low abstraction level - fairly reliable. But there is a problem - your experience is described in the question as VB, PHP, etc. IMO, you simply can't make such project in assembly language. The expertise is not enough.

Comment: Spacecraft have rudders?

Comment: @MartinJames: The Space Shuttle certainly does.

Answer (score 5):

As somebody who did a lot of embedded systems programming in the past, I would strongly encourage you to prototype it in C. That will let you concentrate on your algorithms, control flow, and error handling without getting bogged down in the minutiae of indexing modes and individual instruction optimization. The most important thing is that your control system actually *works*.

Another benefit of prototyping in C is that you can do a large part of the prototyping on a Windows or Linux system that has modern development tools: editors, development environments, debuggers, etc. That makes a huge difference in turnaround time.

After you've proved that your algorithms are sound, you can profile the system to determine how much memory it occupies and whether it's fast enough. There are many good C compilers for embedded systems, and it's very likely that if you use efficient algorithms the system will be plenty efficient without having to delve into hand-coded assembly language. Remember, good algorithm selection can give you orders of magnitude increases in speed. In most cases, hand coded assembly language can only give (at best) small multiples of performance gains. Often, the improvement is small percentages (less than 10%).

Make it work. Then make it small and fast.

As far as learning assembly language, I think every programmer should. Which processor doesn't really matter. I disagree with the comments about learning x86 as a first assembly language. The key lessons have little to do with the particular instruction set or register organization. The most important thing is learning to think at the lower level: per-instruction rather than per-statement. I personally know dozens of programmers whose first assembly language was x86, and I don't find them as a group any better or any worse than those who learned some other assembly language. And the benefits of studying x86 are many: there are many people from whom you can learn, there's a whole lot of good tutorial information available, there are several good free assemblers, and even emulators and development environments, all free and well supported. For those reasons, I'd be hard pressed to recommend anything else for a first-time assembly language.

Comment: Downvoter: something in particular you disagree with?

Comment: Thanks, that's extremely helpful. I'd upvote if I had enough reputation :)